# Proxmox Mail Gateway 6.0-4 free not quarantining spam

Tags: email, mail-server, proxmox

I installed Proxmox Mail Gateway 6.0-4 free as an antispam server for a mail server. It works fine, but except one thing. In the Proxmox Mail Gateway has an option Spam Quarantine. It is empty. I do not see there the spam letters. Maybe does it need activate or enable the Spam Quarantine module?